# Solve PlatformException (PlatformException(user-not-found)) Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I don't know how to handle this exception launched by Firebase.

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(user-not-found, There is no user record corresponding `to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., 
{code: user-not-found, message: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., 
nativeErrorMessage: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., nativeErrorCode: 17011, additionalData: {}}, null)).
```

This is the code, it comes from "loginWithEmailAndPassword" :

```
Future<void> submit(
      context, FirebaseAuth authF, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final userCredential = await authF.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        LogInCupertinoDialogue(context);
      } else {
        LogInAndroidDialogue(context);
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

User doesn't exists, this is what I need to handle.
EDIT : For "handle" I mean that if a non registered user try to login my app crashes. I don't want it! If it should crash just launch the window dialogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, the following should do the trick:

```
      } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {

           // Display the error message that user doesn't exists

        } else {

           // Display a more global error message

        }
      } ...
```

You can detect the code from the exception details:

> PlatformException (PlatformException(user-not-found, There is no user
> record corresponding `to this identifier. The user may have been
> deleted., {**code: user-not-found**,...

---

Note: You'll find in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#error-codes_12) the list of the potential error codes returned by `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`.

Comment: No, the problem is that I don't want that the app crashes. I already used a try and catch but however when I try to signIn a non registered user it crashes.

Comment: I just want to avoid the freeze or crash of the application after calling signInWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: Normally the exception should not crash your app. There is probably another reason. What happens if instead of calling `LogInXXXXDialogue(context);` you just do `print()`?

Comment: Same result...I did some researches and I found that maybe I'm not well handling the exception...Maybe I should use the "e" from try and catch.

Answer (score 0):

you can use exception code to detect different exception then use a dialog for showing it to user here is a simple example:-

```
Future<User> signin(String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  try {
    UserCredential result =
        await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: email);
    User user = result.user;
    return Future.value(user);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.code);
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
      case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
      case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
      case 'ERROR_USER_DISABLED':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
      case 'ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
      case 'ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED':
        showErrDialog(context, e.code);
        break;
    }

showErrDialog(BuildContext context, String err) {
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    child: AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Error"),
      content: Text(err),
      actions: <Widget>[
        OutlineButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text("Ok"),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the platformExeption with FirebaseException

```
 } on FirebaseException  catch (err) { 
  var message = "An error occurred, please check your credential";
  if (err.message != null) {
    message = err.message;
  }
  print("error message : $message");
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctx).errorColor,
    ),
  );
```